# The PHP temporary folder is not writeable

Tags: php, permissions, linux

On Joomla 5 (same problem on Joomla 4) I am getting the warning "The PHP temporary folder is not writeable". In more detail:

`This folder is not writeable by the Joomla! instance, which may cause issues when trying to upload extensions to Joomla. If you are having issues uploading extensions, check the '/tmp-upload' and set it to be writeable and see if this fixes the issue.`

The folder permissions are 777, as shown in the screenshot below of the folder permissions as shown in Midnight Commander (connecting to the server via SSH).

[image: tmp folder permissions]

I've read quite a few articles and posts on this point, and as far as I can tell I have done everything that needs to be done.

Either I am missing something or there is a bug in Joomla. I'm inclined to think that the former is more likely in this case, so I would be grateful for any help that can be offered.

I'm running Joomla under Ubuntu 22.04 with the CyberPanel (v. 2.4) control panel on my own local server. (The problems seem to be the same on other machines, though.)

Thank you!

Comment: This can be safely ignored or set `upload_tmp_dir` to a suitable value. For details, see: https://joomla.stackexchange.com/a/32332/120